# Parsing XML with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs, parsing

I am trying to parse an XML file with AngularJS. The tutorial which I am following is given below.

[Tutorial](http://motyar.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-parse-xml-in-angular-js.html)

The file which I am trying to parse is given below.

[API File](http://www.supermarketapi.com/api.asmx/COMMERCIAL_SearchByProductName?APIKEY=APIKEY&ItemName=Parsley)

However after many attempts , I am not able to get the **Price** or any other dimension from the XML.
The code which I have minutely **altered** is given below.

**Code**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://demos.amitavroy.com/learningci/assets/js/xml2json.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Parsing XML in ajgularJS</title> 
</head>
<body ng-app="todosApp">
    <h2>Parsing XML data with AngularJS</h2>
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
    <div ng-controller="todos"><ol><li ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter:search">{{todo.Pricing}}</div>
    <script>
        var todoApp = angular.module('todosApp',[]);

        todoApp.factory('todoFactory',function($http){
          var factory = [];

        factory.getTodos = function(){
          return $http.get("http://www.supermarketapi.com/api.asmx/COMMERCIAL_SearchByProductName?APIKEY=APIKEY&ItemName=Juice");
          }

          return factory;
        });

        todoApp.controller('todos',function($scope,todoFactory){

          $scope.todos = [];
          loadTodos();

        function loadTodos(){
            todoFactory.getTodos().success(function(data){
                product  = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
                console.log(product.Product_Commercial);
                $scope.todos = product.Product_Commercial;
            });
            }
        });
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unless API is CORS enabled you can't get xml cross domain with javascript

Comment: @charlietfl Can you please explain bit more about it. Do we have any other option to get this detail.

Comment: do some web surfing. There are literally thousands of posts on this site alone about cross domain ajax

Comment: what error you get in your console? Is it about cross origin issue?

Comment: @GeekOnGadgets ..Fortunately There is no error. However when I start typing random price then its not giving me any result..